# Why does the Python repl print different things for None?

Tags: python, dictionary

Today I was playing with a Python dict and I found something weird:

```
>>> print {}.get('non-existant-key')

>>> a = {}.get('non-existant-key')
>>> print a
None
>>>
```

Why does the repl print an empty space with the first print and "None" after taking the step of storing the value in the variable `a`? The thing it tries to print is the same in both cases, so why is there be a difference?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? I've tried 2.7.8 (because you're using the Python2 version of `print`) and the first statement prints out `None` for me.

Comment: In version `3.4.3` output the same with `print({}.get('non-existant-key'))`

Comment: when I do the `print {}.get('non-existant-key')` I get `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, turns out it wasn't the behaviour of the Python repl, but the (for the rest excellent) [bpython repl](http://bpython-interpreter.org/) which I always use. I didn't realise I was using bpython instead of the vanilla python when I was testing this.

In the regular pyton repl it all works as expected. I'll file a bug with bpython about this.